# Service for loading additional levels of pictures into the game

Tags: ios, swift, image

There is a game with pictures, initially it is loaded with 100 levels (400 pictures).
I want to make the [Load new levels] button, so that I do not add and do not heavily play the game in the AppStore.

Tell me how to implement the loading of new pictures, for example, that the user clicked on the DOWNLOAD button and another 400 pictures would be loaded into the game.

Those. The question is even where I put these pictures, then in the game checking that there is an update of the levels, the user could download them to the device (phone) and use offline. This is a one-time download.

Thank you.

Comment: I understand the questions novices in programming on this service are forbidden to ask, since I get more minuses than answers(

Answer (score 0):

You can use **On-Demand Resources**

on-demand resources, a new API in iOS 9 for delivering content to your applications while also reducing the amount of space the application takes up on the user's device. With on-demand resources, you can tag specific assets of your application, have them hosted on Apple's servers, allowing your users to download them when needed.

[Apple link](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/On_Demand_Resources_Guide/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015083-CH2-SW1)

[Tutorial link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-on-demand-resources-on-ios-and-tvos--cms-24929)

Comment: No. I need for earlier ios too. In many games (4 pictures 1 word) there is a button (download new levels), I just do not understand where to put new pictures for downloading? I have a picture folder where I download it, so that the user presses a button and gets them into the game. I understand that this may be a stupid question, but I have never encountered this

Comment: You can create a api for fetch images from your server and save to document directory of your app and use in future from document directory.